# Retrieve Hash values with key in a specific date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I'm using Rails. I've stored a count by month in a postgres db as a hash using hstore.

The stored hash is formatted as follows:

{"2017-03-01 00:00:00 UTC"=>"10", "2017-04-01 00:00:00 UTC"=>"3"}

I'm struggling to find a great way to retrieve specific month counts from this hash due to the date format used for the key.

QUESTION

What is the best way to format a string to match the current hash key date format?

- For example for March in the Hash the key is "2017-03-01 00:00:00 UTC"
- However, a new DateTime for March 1 2017 is formatted as "2017-03-01T00:00:00+00:00"

Or is it best to change the format of how I am storing the hash in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a timestamp in a specific format, the standard tool to use is [`DateTime#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) (all the time-ish classes will have a `strftime` method and they all behave the same). In your case:

```
some_datetime.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

And hooking that up to ActiveRecord:

```
Model.where('your_hstore -> :key', :key => some_datetime.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'))
```

Or:

```
Model.where('your_hstore -> ?', some_datetime.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'))
```

---

`%Z` should be the "Time zone abbreviation name" and for me it produces strings like `'UTC'`, `'PDT'`, ... If your `strftime` (which almost certainly is just a wrapper around the system's libc version of `strftime`) doesn't produce the strings that you want then you have some options:

1. Drop the timezone completely if it will always be UTC. Then the keys would look like `2017-03-01 00:00:00` and you'd use `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` as your `strftime` format string.
2. If they keys are actually just dates as they appear to be, then use dates and drop the time-of-day. Then your keys would look like `2017-03-01`, you'd use `Date` instances in Ruby rather than `DateTime`s, and you'd say `some_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` or `some_date.iso8601` in Ruby to get your hstore keys.
3. If you are using non-UTC timezones, then convert everything to UTC and go with **1** or **2**.
4. If you don't want any of the above, switch to numeric timezone offsets (2017-05-10 18:05:57 +0000, 2017-05-10 18:06:48 +00:00, ...) and use `%z`, `%:z`, or `%::z` in the `strftime` format string (see the docs for difference between these three).

These of course require reworking any data you already have in the database but it is best to get the out of the way sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still struggling to find the right strftime format combination. What you have above .utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' results in = 2017-03-01 00:00:00 +00:00

Comment: `%Z` gives me nice things like UTC, PDT, ... but there are options. Have a look at my updated answer. For the record, timezones are evil.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out why %Z in strftime was not resulting in UTC for the timezone. I ended up striping it out of the hash stored in the db which is a much better solution overall. Thank you for your help!!